# Where can I find a free LXX/English interlinear?

Tags: septuagint, resource-request

I'm looking for an interlinear Greek English Septuagint Old Testament. Is there a free one?

Comment: If you find one, let me know.

Comment: This is helpful  https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/default.asp  not quite interlinear but close

Comment: [Link](http://www.greekdoc.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the free [Apostolic Bible Polyglot](https://www.apostolicbible.com/text.htm), which contains the text of the Old and New Testament in Greek, with an interlinear English translation. It's also available at [biblehub.com](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/apostolic/). However, the Greek text is monotonic and without breathing marks.

Comment: This is great! You guys are so knowledgeable.

Comment: Couple of additions to the list:  https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/default.asp [side/side - I cannot speak to the quality but it is useful],  https://biblebento.com/index.html?lxx1i&290.1.1 [more 'true interlinear'; would appreciate assessment by experts]